# Redirect problem: How to redirect to the original URL after login

Tags: redirect, login

I am using BBPress. Links to the forum (for example: https://www.xy.com/topic/test/) are being redirected to a custom login page like so:

```
if ( is_bbpress() && !is_user_logged_in() ) {

 wp_redirect( 'https://www.xy.com/intranet'); }
```

The users can successfully login, but unfortunately always end up on the same page since the redirect causes a loss of the original URL. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

```
if ( is_bbpress() && !is_user_logged_in() ) {
  wp_redirect( 'https://www.xy.com/intranet');  // if this redirects to your login page 
}
```

**And this is your login form:**

```
$args = array(
        'echo' => true,
        'redirect' => site_url( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ), // this will redirect
        'form_id' => 'loginform',
        'label_username' => __( 'Username' ),
        'label_password' => __( 'Password' ),
        'label_remember' => __( 'Remember Me' ),
        'label_log_in' => __( 'Log In' ),
        'id_username' => 'user_login',
        'id_password' => 'user_pass',
        'id_remember' => 'rememberme',
        'id_submit' => 'wp-submit',
        'remember' => true,
        'value_username' => NULL,
        'value_remember' => false );

wp_login_form( $args );
```

So what happens above us this:

- If you are on BB and you are not logged in, your will be redirected to the login page
- And once you are logged in, you will return to the previous page

I haven't tested the script, but it is logically correct.

Comment: Can you also explain, what it does please?

Comment: Thanks for the answer! That doesn't seem to work though. The referring link gets lost when redirecting to the login page already.

Comment: I think I know what the problem is... I have updated the script for you above.